# Kendo Grid: avoid dataSource read() when exporting to excel

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have a page with a Kendo Grid. The read method from the dataSource calls a custom REST API which takes around 15 seconds and returns over 2,000 records. 
When the user hits the "Export" button, by looking at the browser's Network tab, I see that the read method is triggered again.

Why isn't the export feature using the records that have already been loaded? I tried removing the `pageSize` and `allPages` properties but nothing has changed.

Is this Kendo's default behavior? If so, are there any workarounds so that the service is not called again?

HTML:

```
<div kendo-grid="grid"</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.grid = {
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/...",
                cache: false
            }
        },
        schema: { ... },
        pageSize: 20
    },
    toolbar: ["excel"],
    excel: {
        fileName: "xxx.xlsx",
        allPages: true
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> When the allPages option is set to true and serverPaging is enabled,
>   the Grid will make a "read" request for all data. If the data items
>   are too many the browser may become unresponsive. Consider
>   implementing server-side export for such cases.

[Docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/excel-export)

[Server Side Export](https://github.com/tareknaj/kendo-grid-export-excel)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I was aware of this. I should have mentioned that I tried removing both allPages and pageSize options but nothing changed. I have not updated my question including this.